# QSqlDatabase доступ

Tags: qt, qsqldatabase

У меня в QMainWindow есть главный объект QSqlDatabase database. Этот объект используется для доступа ко всем данным (даже секретным). Но к этому объекты должны иметь доступ производные (дочерние окна). Как это сделать?

Comment: Стоит самостоятельно поискать решение в интернете прежде чем задавать вопрос на каком либо ресурсе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как только соединение установлено, можно вызвать статическую функцию QSqlDatabase::database() из любого места программы с указанием имени соединения, чтобы получить указатель на это соединение. Если не передать имя соединения, она вернет соединение по умолчанию.

[original](https://habrahabr.ru/post/51650/)

Answer (score 0):

И снова здравствуйте)

Например можно использовать синглтон, который будет отвечать за этот объект.

```
class DBProvider
{
  public:
    static QSqlDatabase& database()
    {
       return  DBProvider::instance()->m_database;
    }


  private:
    QSqlDatabase m_database;

    static DBProvider& instance()
    {
        static DBProvider dbPr;
        dbPr.m_database =  QSqlDatabase::database("connectname123", true);
        return dbPr;
    }

    DBProvider() 
    { 
       //подключаетесь к базе: m_database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(..., "connectname123");
    }

    ~DBProvider() { } 

    DBProvider(DBProvider const&); 
    DBProvider& operator= (DBProvider const&); 
};
```